# Comma separated text in attribute tables

Tags: attribute-table, fields-attributes, select-by-attribute, search

I'm creating a shapefile of all the sports units of a state in India. Units can have multiple infrastructure. There are 6 kinds of infrastructure. Sometimes a single unit can have multiple infrastructure. So, I have "Type_of_Infrastructure" as one attribute. Now, while building the attribute table for the shapefile, for "Type_of_Infrastructure", if a unit is of 4 infrastructure types, can I write the names of 4 types in a single cell? Will it be easy for query and search?

Or is it better I create 6 different columns in the attribute table for each kind of infrastructure?

Comment: Proper normalized relational structure would be to have separate table with facility ID and infrastructure type (lists in fields are difficult to process, and duplicate geometries cause other issues).

Comment: Maybe you should choose geopackage format instead. In which GIS software are you working?

Comment: As said by @Vince if you are using a rdbms the "proper" way would be a related infrastructure table (1-n relationship), but if you don't want to go this way (or feel it's unnecessary in this specific case) then having a (numeric) column for each type of infrastructure filled with 0/1 is probably the way to go (it will be easier for query and search and it will be easy to fill a text field with comma separated value if you need to)